# What is the origin of "moral support"?

Tags: etymology

Why is the phrase "moral support" used, when it seems like it would more accurately be "morale support"?

Is this just a misspelling that has become canon, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the *Online Etymology Dictionary*, *moral* originally meant "pertaining to character as opposed to physical action."  It did not originally relate to social values or manners.  So *moral support* means support that is intangible rather than financial, military, or other physical support.

I found this through Dictionary.com: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moral.

Answer (score 4):

[Etymology Online says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=moral) that the original meaning of the word "moral" was

> "pertaining to character or temperament" (good or bad)

And that this meaning is retained in the phrase "moral support":

> with sense of "pertaining to character as opposed to physical action."

Answer (score 1):

*Moral support* means "support or help, the effect of which is psychological rather than physical."
*Morale* means "the confidence, enthusiasm, and discipline of a person or group at a particular time."

> Their morale was high.

*Morale support* is not a phrase I have ever heard, and it would not have the same meaning of *moral support*.

Comment: "as" moral support.